# Permanently set default audio device

Tags: windows-10

In the environment where I'm working we are working with flexible workplaces. We use laptops and connect them with dockingstations (Lenovo ThinkPad USB 3.0 Pro Dock 40A70045EU) to an external monitor, keyboard, mouse and wired internetconnection. I want to set my default playback device to the internal soundcard (Realtek high definition audio), but when connecting to the dockingstation using an USB-cable the default audio playback device changes to the audio device of the dockingstation. When the default audio device is changed it will remember it for that particular dockingstation, but when connecting to a different one (for one that those setting haven't been applied yet) it changes it nonetheless. It's not difficult to change it, but it's annoying to do it every time I connect to a dockingstation for which I haven't applied it yet. With a few hundred workplaces the chance of sitting at a desk for which it hasn't been changed yet is quite big.

Is there an method to change the default audio device to the internal soundcard permanently?
Is there a way to change it either with a script that runs at startup, a change in a registry-setting or maybe a GPO?